# How to get pose from april tag topic tag_detection?

Tags: c++, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Currently, I have a bag file which publishes the /tag_detections coming from apriltag node.
I'm having trouble in writing a callback function which could extract information like pose from the topic.

The details of the topic are:

```
rosmsg show apriltag_ros/AprilTagDetectionArray

std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
apriltag_ros/AprilTagDetection[] detections
  int32[] id
  float64[] size
  geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped pose
    std_msgs/Header header
      uint32 seq
      time stamp
      string frame_id
    geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose
      geometry_msgs/Pose pose
        geometry_msgs/Point position
          float64 x
          float64 y
          float64 z
        geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
          float64 x
          float64 y
          float64 z
          float64 w
      float64[36] covariance
```

The piece of code that I manage to write till now is:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "apriltag_ros/AprilTagDetectionArray.h"


void callback(const apriltag_ros::AprilTagDetectionArray::ConstPtr &msg)
{
    //What to do?
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "apriltag_location");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("tag_detections",1000,callback);
    ros::spin();

}
```

Could someone point out on how to get the pose from here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344153/how-to-get-pose-from-april-tag-topic-tag_detection?/) by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2020-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pose is the `msg->detections[i].pose` of type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance` for all `N` detections.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-02-14**:
Could you explain what 'i' here would be?

```
geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovariance x;
x = msg->detections[0].pose.pose;
ROS_INFO("[%f]",x.pose.position.x);
```

Writing like gives me a message 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-14**:
I think your issue here is not really understanding C++ rather than a ROS-specific issue. I'd recommend going through some C++ STL tutorials and  then coming back to revisit to this.

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-02-14**:
That is true, thanks for the input.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-14**:
If I've answered your question, can you hit the checkmark so its removed from our unanswered questions queue?